# Require old password to make new password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, form-for

Right now every time I change anything in user/edit the form requires the user to set a new password. I would like for it to require the current password (how can I ask for current password?) only incase a new password is entered. How can I achieve this, thanks a lot for this.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Enter new password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm new password" %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using some info from rails_has_elegance and the web I came up with the following solution.

user/edit view:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: :email %>
  <%= password_field_tag :current_password, params[:current_password], placeholder: "Current password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "New password (optional)" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm new password" %>
<% end %>
```

User model:

```
validates :password, :on => :create
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :on => :update, :unless => lambda{ |user| user.password.blank? }
```

User controller:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  user = User.find_by_email(current_user.email).try(:authenticate, params[:current_password])
  if user && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Incorrect Current Password" unless user
    sign_in @user
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add in your form old_password field

```
<%= f.password_field :old_password, placeholder: "Enter current password" %>
```

Add it to `attr_accessible :old_password` and `attr_accessor :old_password`

And then you can validate it

```
validate :correct_old_pass, :on => :update

def correct_old_pass
  errors[:old_password] << 'Incorrect pass' if your_check_method
end
```

Comment: I assume I should but attr access in the user model? still unkown attribute. Don't I need a way to validate the old password as well. something like <%= f.password_field @user.authenticate([:password]), placeholder: "Enter current password" %> make any sense?

Comment: add to your attr_accessible list in model :old_password, then it will be available as attribute in model and you can validate it

Comment: <%= f.password_field @user.authenticate([:password]), placeholder: "Enter current password" %> make any sense?
Seems to me it have no sense

Comment: I get ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UsersController#update for :old_password

Comment: You have to add attr_accessor :old_password to, my fault

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate form for changing password. And you can ask for current password just like you ask for a new one:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Enter current password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Enter new password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm new password" %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't getting how can it help?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making extra edit_password and update_password actions for that in your users_controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
user = User.find_by_email(current_user.email).try(:authenticate, params[:current_password])
if user && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  flash[:success] = "Password updated!"
  (sign_in @user)
  redirect_to ...
```

In your form just use these fields:

```
  <%= label_tag :current_password, "Current password:" %>
  <%= password_field_tag :current_password, params[:current_password] %>

  <%= form.label :password, "New password:" %>
  <%= form.password_field :password %>

  <%= form.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %>
  <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

Comment: When I enter the current password incorrectly I don't receive any errors messages from render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object

Comment: that's true, you could do this manually with a flash[:error] = ""

Comment: Yep just did that, has to be flash.now so it only stays for current page