# How to update user password using password_digest and form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the below files to update a users details. they currently work for everything except for the password. all of the logic is working correctly, I have used `puts` to check that the correct sections of logic are entered however it seems that the password never gets updated at the end when `@user.update(user_params)` is called.

To get this to work I have to add the 2 lines below into the password logic in UserController which doesn't seem logical given that I call `@user.update(user_params)` further on which should update the user with the user parameters provided. Any advice, suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated.

```
@user.password = params[:user][:password]
@user.save
```

I'm not using any Gems etc for the authentication and my user table looks like the following

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.string "firstName"
    t.string "surname"
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
end
```

**UserController**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :authorized, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_user, only: [:update]
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password))
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to '/welcome'
  end

  def update
    errorMessage = ''
    if current_user.username != params[:user][:username]
      if User.find_by(username: params[:user][:username]).nil?
      else
        errorMessage += "Username is already taken"
      end
    else
    end
    if !params[:user][:password].blank?
      if @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password_confirmation])
      else
        errorMessage += "Confirmation password is incorrect"
      end
    else
    end

    if !errorMessage.blank?
      redirect_to account_path, notice: errorMessage
    else
      @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to account_path
    end
  end

  private 
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :title, :firstName, :surname,:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<p id=”notice”><%= notice %></p>
<%= form_for current_user do |f|%>
    <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
        <%= f.label :username, class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label"%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :username, class:"form-control col-sm-10" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <%= f.label :title%><br>
            <%= f.text_field :title, class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <%= f.label :firstName, "First Name" %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :firstName, class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <%= f.label :surname %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :surname, class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Current Password"%><br>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= f.label :password, "New Password"%><br>
            <%= f.password_field :password, class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
        <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted col-md-12">
            To update your password, please confirm your current password.
        </small>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" ,class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
end
```

Comment: Can you add your `User` model code?

Comment: I have added this

Comment: Seems to be straight forward: https://medium.com/@ashleymcolletti/add-authentication-to-your-rails-app-with-bcrypt-a53917252159

Comment: The post attached only shows how you create a user, I can already do that. I want to be able to change the password of an existing user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your controller is a bit complex, I assume that this is somehow causing your problem. You should output the errors in the view to see what's going wrong, this was unfortunately not part of your question.

Nevertheless, in general, there are **two options** to get this working described in the [bcrypt ruby Github repository](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby). Note, I have not tried with `current_user`, `params[:user]` and `@user.authenticate` to remove complexity and concentrate on the bcrypt topic.

#### Option 1

Using `has_secure_password` in your user model like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
end
```

You need a password digest column and you need to work with `:password` in your user_params method.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :title, :firstName, :surname, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

The entered password would be saved in the database in the `password_digest`  column.

#### Option 2

This is described on the [the-user-model part of the bcrypt Github page](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby#the-user-model).

In this case, you do NOT use `has_secure_password` but add the following code to your user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include BCrypt

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end
end
```

Then your `user_params` method needs to reflect the `:password_hash` attribute name:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :title, :firstName, :surname, :password_hash, :password_confirmation)
end
```

In this case, your database would need a `password_hash` column instead of `password_digest` to get it working using the sample code above. Of course, you could also re-use `password_digest` instead of `password_hash`, then replace `password_hash` in the above code with `password_digest`.

#### Notes

In both cases I use a view as you did with a `password` field:

```
<div class="form-group row col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :password, "New Password"%><br>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The controller in my tests looked like this:

```
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

#### Test app

I have also added this little test rails app using option 1 with `has_secure_password` into a Github repository @ https://github.com/cadamini/rails-bcrypt-ruby-test

Comment: With regards to Option 1
I am already doing that as can be seen in the attached code

Comment: Then you need to tell us the error message you get. It might fail silently in another place, e.g. authenticate.

Comment: I don't get an error message, If I change the controller to work the same as you have put above then it works for all other fields except for password

Comment: I have updated the test repo with two things - Current password check and the need for the user to confirm the new password. Check it out again at  https://github.com/cadamini/rails-bcrypt-ruby-test. For this, I have used the method suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15829023/3842598 - maybe this is a starting point for you to find the problem with your password_digests.

Comment: Thank you, that's helped greatly :)

Answer (score 1):

Open `app/models/user.rb` and add the method `has_secure_password` to your `User` class. `has_secure_password`and `password_digest` work together in bcrypt, so both need to be present for it to work.

Comment: I already have this in my code. I've edited the question to include the User Model